# Is there an expression to describe a cover band that still has members of the original band?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I recently went to a show that was played by a [Heart by Heart](https://www.heartbyheart.com/). It's a cover band that focus on playing [Heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_(band)) songs, but with the added appeal of having two of the original band's members: Steve Fossen and Michael Derosier.

A band isn't solely identified by the lead singer, so Heart by Heart having a different vocalist than the original Heart makes me feel like Cover Band is the wrong terminology. After all, two of the band's members are playing their own songs!

Comment: a half-cover band?

Comment: _Semi-cover, coverlet_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [list](https://www.yardbarker.com/entertainment/articles/the_most_successful_musical_spinoff_groups/s1__31457969) I found of famous spin-off musical groups or bands (not necessarily cover bands), where some members of a disbanded musical group later form a new one including some of their former band members.

Spin-off, sense 2 or 3 from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spin-off) Dictionary:

> 2: a collateral or derived product or effect: BY-PRODUCT
>
> 3: something that is imitative or derivative of an earlier work, product, or establishment

Answer (score 1):

This could be called a **successor**, that is, something that **succeeds** the original in the sense of ([from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succeed)):

> 1a : to come next after another in office or position or in possession of an estate
>
> *especially* : to inherit sovereignty, rank, or title
>
> b : to follow after another in order

Answer (score -3):

I agree, that would not be a cover band. You could just say it's the new line-up of Heart by Heart.

Comment: This answer doesn't work, as there's no suggestion that the current band *Heart by Heart* has changed its line-up.